# Correct values are not passed on serializing an object

Tags: java, serialization

This is the file Employee.java which I am serializing:

```
import java.io.Externalizable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;
import java.util.Date;

public class Employee implements Externalizable {
String lName;
String fName;
double salary;
String address;
Date hireDate;
int id;
@Override
public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    out.writeDouble(salary);
    out.writeInt(id);
}
@Override
public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    salary= in.readDouble();
    id= in.readInt();
} 
}
```

This is code from where I am actually serializing it

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.Date;
 public class ClassA {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Employee emp= new Employee();
    emp.salary= 2000;
    emp.id= 234;
    FileOutputStream fos= null;
    ObjectOutput oos= null;
    try{
        fos= new FileOutputStream("C:\\dkbexternalizable.ser");
        oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    //  oos.writeObject(emp);
        emp.writeExternal(oos);
        oos.flush();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        try {
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The employee object has been serialized into "+"C:\\dkbexternalizable.ser");
    }

}
```

When I debug the serialization code above, I see that 0.0 and 0 are passed for salary and id values in the .ser file.
I want 2000 and 234 to be passed into them instead.
There is some basic mistake which I am unable to figure out . Can someone please help me?

Comment: ok I figured out the problem
I had to use this.salary in the readExternal method

Comment: Why are you using `Externalizable` at all?

Comment: if you don't want other fields(except salary an id) to be serialized, mark them as transient and use Serializable interface instead of Externalizable

Comment: Also, don't directly call writeExternal(),  use writeObject().

Comment: Chuck's comment is in fact the answer.